# how to remove keyup event listeners by javascript

Tags: javascript, events, google-search-api

I'm using the Google autocomplete api on a text field to suggest locations as you type.
The main problem I have with this is that Google does not let you limit results to a specific country, it just lets you bias results to area bounds which is kind of useless.

So seaching for term `"ru"` will give you Russia in suggestions even your region is set to somewhere in Europe.

I realized though that if you put for example "france ru" it gives you france locations only matching ru which is perfect.

So my problem is that the autocomple is completely built by google javascript.

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

So I cannot easily fiddle with search string to add in to it constantly `"france"`

I can see what is bound to the `onkeyup` event on that field and can take it and call it myself however I cannot unbind it from keyup. I tried several solutions how to do it but can't find a way. jQuery unbind won't work as this is not bound through it obviously. Native functions want a reference to a function bind to listener but this is annonymous function in it. Found some examples using loops over `element.data['events']` but I get data undefined error.

Has anyone solution to unbind all what is register in onkeyup ?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned jQuery, so I'll use that:

`$(input).data('events').keyup` is the array that will contain all the `keyup` handlers. If there is only one keyup event used by Autocomplete, you can hijack the handler to first run whatever function you need, then run the original:

```
var originalKeyup = $(input).data('events').keyup[0].handler;
$(input).data('events').keyup[0].handler = function(){
    // your code here, where you can add 'france' to input.value

    // fire the old function
    originalKeyup.apply(this,arguments);
};
```

You could also just remove the original event handler from the keyup array, and bind new ones that will do what you want.

---

UPDATE:
You could hijack Element.prototype.addEventListener (BEFORE ALL OTHER CODE) to add an `events` property to the Element which will contain any handlers added by any code:

```
var oldAddEventListener = Element.prototype.addEventListener || Element.prototype.attachEvent;
Element.prototype.addEventListener = Element.prototype.attachEvent = function(type, handler){
    this.events = this.events || {};
    this.events[type] = this.events[type] || [];
    this.events[type].push({handler: handler})
    oldAddEventListener.apply(this,arguments);
};
```

Now, every time addEventListener is called, by jQuery or otherwise, the Element's `events` property should be updated with the current events. You may also want to hijack `removeEventListener` to remove the corresponding event from the `events` object when `removeEventListener` is called:

```
var oldREL = Element.prototype.removeEventListener || Element.prototype.detachEvent;
Element.prototype.removeEventListener = Element.prototype.detachEvent = function(type, handler){
    this.oldREL.apply(this,arguments);
    if(this.events && this.events[type]){
        for(var i=this.events[type].length-1; i>=0; i--){
            if(this.events[type][i].handler == handler){
                this.events[type].splice(i,1);
                break; // remove only the first occurrence from the end
            }
        }
        if(this.events[type].length==0){
            delete this.events[type];
        }
    }
```

};

Now you should be able to inspect all events registered on any element. You can remove all `'keyup'` events by iterating over the `input.events.keyup` object and using `input.removeEventListener`.

The `attachEvent` and `detachEvent` are used by IE<9. I don't have IE, so it hasn't been tested there. It works well in Safari 5. Let me know if you have issues in other browsers.

NOTE: These mods need to be in place BEFORE any other code is executed on the page.

---

Update:
Apparently, this will not work in FF or Opera. Changing `Element` to `HTMLInputElement` in the code will fix the problem.

Comment: thnaks for answer. but my input element has data('events') undefined.
used selector to construct element and also tried wrap javascript dom element to jquery objet. both are well constructed but data('events') is just not defined. Tried chrome and ff.

Comment: I updated my answer with a possible solution. See if it works for you.

Comment: nope ;o( I'm using chrome. Added the code to override add and remove listeners in script tag to head before any other js is loaded. I get no error but events is still undefined.

Comment: note that my approach is does NOT make `$(...).data('events')` work. It just adds an `events` object onto the DOM element where the event is bound. So, you'd have to use `document.getElementById('inputElement').events` or `$('#inputElement')[0].events` to get at the events...

Comment: I checked the native element as well and couldn't see events objects there as well.. Anyway I'll try to build an example page and make it work there first. will come back, thank you.

Comment: Hi again.. we've got the example page. Problem that I could not see events object on element was that I was checking it right after calling autocomplete creation which possibly did not allow enough time to be created by google stuff and events registered. So we've got it working prefectly in chrome and surprisingly in IE, but its not working in FF and Opera. events object is just undefined there. check out this example page http://www.lampwebdevelopers.com/example.html

Comment: ok, change every ocurrence of `Element` to `HTMLInputElement`. This makes it work in Safari, FF, and Chrome. Haven't tested IE and Opera.

Comment: Thanks for your help we have it more less working fine although there are little imperfections. And also it does not work in opera, at least it is not failing just not letting overide the add event handler so it is not limited to country we want. Not a lot of users with Opera on our site so we can live with it. thanks again.

Comment: Hi again... after time we found that IE8,7 are still not working well. actually the events is still undefined on these browsers. lampwebdevelopers.com/example.html, what do you think could help it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding the autocomplete to the current map bounds, [as shown in the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html): `autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map)` ?

Comment: yes I did that at first but its useless because suggestions are kind of ordered by weight which is combination of location and hierarchy level. For example ru comes with Russia becaus it is country level. then as you type it comes with close big cities but from all around the europe just because big cities are in hierarchy higher than street match which is close. Don't undertand how this was meant by google but geographical hierarchy of results has too high weight in compare to bounds location for my taste. Try it out...